# adding an interface to all classes

Tags: regex, sed

I have about 300 classes and they now need to implement `Serializable`. I was thinking I could use a `find` and a `sed` to do this.

By find criteria works

```
^public class.*{$
```

In other works find the line with start `Public Class`, has some text and end with a `{`

Now I was to replace it so that the end is actually

```
implemenets MyInterface {
```

The before would be

```
public class MyClass {
```

and

```
public class MyClass2 {
```

and the output would be

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
```

and

```
public class MyClass2 implements MyInterface {
```

I've been looking up backreferences but they seem to be acting funny in Notepad++ where I am testing.

Any tips would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Use the refactoring tools of your IDE for that. They are able to speak Java, sed and awk are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ echo 'public class MyClass {' | sed '/^public class.*{$/s/{$/implements MyInterface {/'
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
```

OR

```
$ echo 'public class MyClass {' | sed 's/^\(public class.*\){$/\1implements MyInterface {/'
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
```

Comment: What if the class already implements an interface and `Serializable` should only be added?

Comment: then `sed '/\bimplements\b/!s/^\(public class.*\){$/\1implements MyInterface {/' file`

Comment: how should this fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Using this `sed -r`:

```
sed -r 's/(public +class +\S+ *)\{/\1 implements MyInterface {/' File.java
```

This will skip the replacement if java file already has `implements MyInterface`. However in Java class declaration there may be many cases where any simple find/replace based on regex will fail.

Comment: and what if it is `public class Foo implements FooInterface` but `MyInterface` should be added to the list?

Comment: Yes I agree @hek2mgl, and being a Java programmer myself I can add many more cases where any simple find/replace will fail.

Comment: Probably you should add this to your answer.

Comment: Sure, I have added it in my answer.